# Getting a Javascript variable out of a $.get statement

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters

EDIT: Please feel free to delete, I have found an appropriate answer in the duplicates mentioned above. Apologies.

I have the following code, and can't seem to dig the variables out correcly:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
     alert(getRemaining(0));
}

function getRemaining(i){   
    var x;          
    $.get('files/remaining.txt', function(file){
        x = file.split(",");            
    });
    return x[i]
}
```

My alert just keeps coming out as undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if I stick an `alert(x);` line in under `x = file.split`, it returns the desired array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `.get` that you run is an asynchronous function. This means that execution of your code will continue on past it BEFORE it completes. The callback function that you pass into `.get` will be called once it is finished (this is the main reason for providing a callback).

This code will alert once the `.get` has returned.

```
$.get('files/remaining.txt', function(file){
    x = file.split(",");   
    alert(x[0]);         
});
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but how do I get `x` out of the `.get` function and useable in a different part of the code after `.get` has finished?

Comment: You won't be able to access x until your callback is called. I'd recommend any code that relies on x be placed into the callback function (if there's a lot of code, you might want to put it into a separate function, then call THAT function inside the callback). If you really need x outside the code somewhere, define a global variable `var global_x = undefined;`, then set it inside your callback. Then anywhere else you need x, be sure to check to make sure it's not undefined before using it.

Comment: Great I think that's done the trick :)